# Template instance in different translation units

Tags: c++, templates, translation-unit

As far as I know, each template have different instances on each translation unit, and for my understanding a translation unit is roughly a `cpp` file.

So, if I have a file named `test.hpp` with the following contents:

```
// test.hpp
template <typename T> void test()
{
    static T t = T(0);
    return t++;
}
```

For each translation unit I should have a different instance of `test` even if the template parameter `T` is the same in each of them. I've decided to test it so I've created the following files (include guards are omitted for the sake of brevity):

```
// a.hpp
namespace A { void f(); }

// a.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "a.hpp"
#include "test.hpp"
namespace A
{
void f() { std::cout << test<int>(); }
}

// b.hpp
namespace B { void f(); }

// b.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "b.hpp"
#include "test.hpp"
namespace B
{
void f() { std::cout << test<int>(); }
}
```

As we can see, both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` uses the `int` instance of the `test()` template but in different translation units, so executing the following program:

```
// main.cpp
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

int main()
{
    A::f();
    B::f();
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting an output of `00` but i get `01` instead. The IDE I'm using to test this code is MSVC2010 V10.0.4 SP1.

So what's the question?

- Is my understanding of the templates and translation units wrong? or...
- I did something wrong with this test code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding of the templates and translation units wrong?

Yes. It's wrong.
A copy of template function is created **per type** and **not per translation unit**.

In your case, for `test<int>` only 1 copy is created and same is used across all the TUs.

Comment: Would you mind to mention where in the standard is this characteristic mentioned?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster See the question suggested as duplicate.

Comment: @Suma thanks: Standard 3.2/5 One Definition Rule. It can be readed [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).

Comment: *A copy of template function is created **per type** and **not per translation unit*** It seems that it also happens with C++14 variable templates (see in[Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HaGW0aa9marEpw19)), isn't it?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, yes that's correct. Since it's templated, anyway it will have only 1 copy. However if you specialize it, then again it will result in multiple definition error. e.g. `template<typename T> T a = 1; template<> int a = 0;`, if you put this  statement in a common header file then the 2nd statement will result in linker error.