# C++14 warning: too many template headers for variable (should be 0)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, template-specialization, variable-templates

While experimenting with the recent g++-5 compiler, I wrote below statement in a file:

```
template<T> T a;
template<> int a = 1;
```

Which results in:

> warning: too many template headers for `a` (should be 0)

Also effectively, it doesn't really specialize `a<int>`. e.g.

```
template<typename T> T a;
template<> int a = 1;

int main ()  {
  std::cout << a<double> << "\n";  // prints 0; OK
  std::cout << a<int> << "\n";  // prints 0! why not 1?
}
```

What is the mystery about this syntax?

Comment: That is an awesomely misleading warning.  I am surprised it was not an error.  Was it the only diagnostic?

Comment: @Yakk, yes in g++-5 that is the only diagnostic. Not sure about clang, though.

Comment: Ah, I think I get the warning now!  It is saying `int a = 1;` should have 0 template headers, where `template<` whatever `>` is one template header.  Imagine if you deleted the `template<class T> T a;` before it -- the warning makes sense.  Still shocking that it is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Coppied from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367350/template-instance-in-different-translation-units/29367507?noredirect=1#comment48217223_29367507) *if you specialize [a variable template], then again it will result in multiple definition error. e.g. `template<typename T> T a = 1; template<> int a = 0;`, if you put this statement in a common header file then the ... statement will result in linker error*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Template arguments can only be omitted in explicit specialisation of *function* templates. You have a variable template, so you have to include the `<int>`:

```
template<> int a<int> = 1;
```

Quoting C++14 (n4140), 14.7.3/10 (emphasis mine):

> A trailing *template-argument* can be left unspecified in the *template-id* naming an explicit **function template
>   specialization** provided it can be deduced from the function argument type.

If you do not want to repeat the type, you can use `auto`:

```
template<> auto a<int> = 1;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e35abf13b4a80ff7) using Clang.

There's one thing to bear in mind with this: when using `auto`, the type of the specialised variable will be deduced from the initialiser, not from the template argument. And since a specialisation can have a different type than the primary template, the compiler will happily accept it even if they differ.

Comment: Interesting, the in between `int` seems redundant to write :-). Anyhow, `template<> auto a<int> = 1;` also works!

Comment: Be careful with `auto` here. If you're expecting the variable to have the same type as the template argument (which won't necessarily match the initialiser), then you might have a surprise.

Comment: @MikeSeymour True indeed, I will add a caveat to the answer.

Comment: Note that you might _intentionally_ want your variable template to have a different type than the type of the template argument.  Usages like `template <class T> bool predicate<T> = false; template<> bool predicate<some_concrete_type> = true;` were probably more what the committee had in mind.

Comment: @zwol I know it's possible to want a different type for the specialisation. It's because it's not what the OP wants here that I added the caveat.