# Warning about too many template headers

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the same warning message as in a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051718/c14-warning-too-many-template-headers-for-variable-should-be-0) but I don't understand how to solve it:

> warning: too many template headers for foo<1>::value (should be 0)
>    int const foo<1>::value = 1;

The warning message appears when one wants to use the following toy header:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO

template<int T>
struct foo;

template<>
struct foo<1>
{ static int const value; };

template<>
int const foo<1>::value = 1;

#endif
```

Can you explain me what the problem is here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `template<>` in your definition of `foo<1>::value` is extraneous. Remove it:

```
template<int T>
struct foo;

template<>
struct foo<1>
{ static int const value; };

int const foo<1>::value = 1;
```

---

`clang++` gives you a much better error:

```
prog.cc:11:1: error: extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'value'
template<>
^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/INxsxcYGqTe8iI9T)

Comment: Thank you very much Vittorio. Your answer is perfect.